# Call component from another module not working

Tags: angular, typescript

**Module to be shared**

exports: [
PatientClinicalTabComponent
],

which is having a emitter patient id

**Module to be Imported**
imports: [
PatientModule
]

**Html Page**

```
<ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <app-patient-clinical-tab [patientId]='patientId'>
      </app-patient-clinical-tab>
    </ng-template>
```

But it showing error when the project is build

**Error:** projects/order/src/app/order-create-edit-tab/order-create-edit-tab.component.html:149:11 - error NG8001: 'app-patient-clinical-tab' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-patient-clinical-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-patient-clinical-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

149           <app-patient-clinical-tab [patientId]='patientId'>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

projects/order/src/app/order-create-edit-tab/order-create-edit-tab.component.ts:15:16
15   templateUrl: './order-create-edit-tab.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component OrderCreateEditTabComponent.

Error: projects/order/src/app/order-create-edit-tab/order-create-edit-tab.component.html:149:37 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'patientId' since it isn't a known property of 'app-patient-clinical-tab'.

1. If 'app-patient-clinical-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'patientId' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-patient-clinical-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.m

149           <app-patient-clinical-tab [patientId]='patientId'>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

projects/order/src/app/order-create-edit-tab/order-create-edit-tab.component.ts:15:16
15   templateUrl: './order-create-edit-tab.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component OrderCreateEditTabComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to options:

- declare `PatientClinicalTabComponent` in `PatientModule`(and nowhere else). Just use it inside `PatientModule`
- create e new module called `PatientClinicalTabModule`. Declare `PatientClinicalTabComponent` inside `PatientClinicalTabModule` and then import `PatientClinicalTabModule` inside `PatientModule`

this will solve your problem